# Why do I have no logs? empty web.stdout.logs?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

So I have an AWS EB environment with and application deployed.

I can't view the applications log output (web.stdout.logs is empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not that I couldn't see the output, it was always in the /var/log/web.stdout.log file however when I was zipping the file to upload it to the EB environment **I was zipping it using the file manager**. This caused an issue on upload as the **Procfile was being placed beside the application rather than inside of it.**
The effect looked like there were no log files, but really the application was just never getting passed to the Procfile.

The solution was

```
cd path/to/application 
zip -r my_application_code.zip .
```

Now when I upload the zip file to the EB console the Procfile is generated correctly and the applications log files are found in web.stdout.log as normal.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding the following to your `python.config`, or by creating new config file, e.g. `mylogs.config`:

```
files: 
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/logtasks/bundle/applogs.conf" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      /opt/python/log/*.log
```

The `/opt/python/log/*.log` should be adjusted to your application.

Comment: Thanks Marcin I will try and report back <3

Comment: Ok so I think don't have it set up right. not yet anyway. How would I manually find the python logs in the s3 bucket?

Comment: @beautysleep Can you ssh into the EB instance and search there. Your app is in `/var/app/current`. So maybe your logs are there?